# Java script XML Reader return empty HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser

I was trying to get all headed tags by parsing xml using DOMParser. Following is my code,

```
function fetchHeaders(text){
    text = '<body><custom h:f="val"><h2></h2></custom></body>';
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
    console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('h2'));
}
```

returns an empty HTML collection instead of `h2` tags.

Without the property `h:f="val"`, it works fine.

Why the tag look up fails when a tag contains property with `:` in it ?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516202/custom-tags-handled-differently-when-using-getelementsbytagname-in-ie-ff)

Comment: Thanks you IslamElshobokshy. But It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml string contains namespace (:h) but is not resolving to anything.

```
var xmlString = '<body xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><custom h:f="val"><h2></h2></custom></body>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('h2'));
```

Alternatively, you can replace all occurences of namespace :h.

```
var xmlString = '<body><custom h:f="val"><h2></h2></custom></body>';
xmlString = xmlString.replace(/h:/g, "");  
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('h2'));
```

Comment: Thank you Jeetaz. Added the first approach it works.

Comment: @Kajal glad it helped! Thanks.